# Add node numbers on a mesh graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, nodes

my script plots a mesh grid using:

```
gplot(adj,NC,'-o')
```

where 'adj' is the adjacency matrix and 'NC' is the matrix of nodes' coordinates. It works absolutely fine, except for the fact that it doesn't show the nodes' numbers on the graph.

For example, for a grid like this:

[image]

I need nodes' numbers to be on the graph and the nodes coordinates matrix is given by:

```
NC =
      0         0
      0         8.455
      0         16.91
      17.385    0
      17.385    8.455
      17.385    16.91
      34.77     0
      34.77     8.455
      34.77     16.91
```

The script also provides the matrix of nodes numbers, which for this example looks like this:

```
A =
     1     4     7
     2     5     8
     3     6     9
```

Nodes' numbers can also be represented as a range k=1:M, where M is known

I believe it is possible to use the above matrices to add the nodes' numbers to the graph, but I don't know how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the labels manually with `text()`:

```
offsetx = 0.5;
offsety = -0.5;
labels  = arrayfun(@(x,y) sprintf('x: %5.2f\ny: %5.2f',x,y), NC(:,1),NC(:,2),'un',0);
labels2 = arrayfun(@(x,y) sprintf('(%g, %g)',x,y), NC(:,1),NC(:,2),'un',0);

text(NC(:,1)+offsetx, NC(:,2)+offsety,labels2)
```

Play a bit with the offsets (you can also define a specific offset for each point) and with the formats (use `labels`, `labels2` or yuor own).

**EDIT** addressing comments

You can use your matrix `A` to create the labels and `offsetx`, `offsety` could be vectors same length as `NC(:,1)`

```
labels = arrayfun(@(x) sprintf('%d',x),A(end:-1:1,:),'un',0);
text(NC(:,1)+offsetx, NC(:,2)+offsety,labels(:))
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code plots nodes' coordinates on the graph, whether I needed it to plot nodes' numbers using the matrix of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I've solved the problem and if anyone interested, here is the code:

```
p=Nw/Ne;
g=Nh/Ne;
for u=1:M1
h=text(NC(u,1)+p,NC(u,2)+g,num2str(u,'%d'));
set(h,'Color',[0 0 1])
end
```

p and g are offsets and they vary since the number of nodes depends on the user's input.